# How can I pass a parameter to a php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to pass a parameter to a php(.js) from html file like this:

> index.html?d=hello

```
<script src="jscript.php?data=$_GET('d')" type="text/javascript" />
```

and php(.js) code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo "document.write ('" . $_GET["data"] . "');";
?>
```

Comment: `<script src="jscript.php?data=<?php echo $_GET('d'); ?>" type="text/javascript" />` i guess?

Comment: but it is a html page (index.html)

Comment: There's no such thing as "parameters" in HTML.

Comment: how can i do it with js

Comment: You can either pass the variables as POST or GET. I'd recommend POST (same as for forms) instead of GET (which is the one with ?= params in link). You can do this using jquery.